# C# thin out list<>

Tags: c#, list

I have a list with, lets say 3600 items. I want to thin out that list using a e.g. factor 5. So there will remain 720 items in the (new) list. But without changing the "course" of the list. The starting and ending point should always remain the same.

Like: **1** -> *skip 30* -> **31**

How to do that?

Comment: Um. What? I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask], please..

Comment: Do you want some kind of sampling on the values? Can you show a better example?

Comment: @Oded If it helps, think of it as 3600 video frames shot at 150 fps... and he wants to _thin it out_ (as he says) to 30 fps... but keep the starting and ending frames.

Comment: Exactly that. And yes, I tried to explain it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
var last = list.Count - 1;
var thin = list.Where ((item, i) => i % 30 == 0 || i == last);
```

If I get your point correctly.

Note that `thin` will be `IEnumerable<int>` and not `List<int>`.
*Usually* this is enough—you can enumerate over it in `foreach` loop and use other LINQ methods.
But it will be evaluated lazily, that is, if your original `list` changes, `thin` will change as well.

If you want to get a `List<int>` instead, just append a `ToList ()` call:

```
var last = list.Count - 1;
var thin = list.Where ((item, i) => i % 30 == 0 || i == last)
               .ToList ();
```

Similarly, to get an array, use `ToArray ()`.

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` for this to work.
See also [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) for more advanced filtration, aggregation and grouping.

Comment: This seems to work like a charm. Clear and professional answer, all I can ask for. Thanks!

Comment: @Felix: Thanks. I added a note that you may want to call `ToList` in some cases, e.g. if `list` is likely to change and you want to keep the current `thin` list as it is, or in case some other API requires you to pass `List<int>` as a parameter.

Comment: Understood. Will keep that in mind..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var thin = list.Where(a => a % 2 == 0).Union(new List<int> { list.Min(), list.Max() }).OrderBy(a => a);
```

This should get the first and last value, plus some in the middle.

Comment: I'm afraid this would be quite inefficient. You're basically traversing the list three times: in `Min`, `Max` and `Where`. Not that it always matters, but I don't think this code wins in readability either.

Comment: Also, I think he meant first and last values, not `Min` and `Max`.